# How to Solve the java.lang.SecurityException:?

Tags: java

How to Solve the Security Exception?

It's shows the Following Error in Client Side. How to Fix it?

> java.lang.SecurityException:class
>   "org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream"'s signer
>   information does not match signer information of other classes in the
>   same package

Comment: What jars do you have in the classpath?

Comment: Bishan: I am using too many jars in here, you asking about any particular jars?

Comment: Do you have `commons-io.jar` in the classpath? Then what is the version?

Comment: yes, I'm using commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar

Comment: Hmmm. Replace it with `commons-io-2.1.jar` and give a try.

Comment: 2.1 also not working, the problem is showing in Linux environment only. 2.4 is correctly working in Windows also.

Answer (score 1):

You've got multiple Jars in your classpath containing the same classes. One or more of them are signed. If a Jar is signed, you can get this error if one class comes from one Jar and another class comes from a different one. This happens most of the time, if you've got the same Jars of different versions or Libraries that added classes of another library to its own Jar.

Finding the culprit and fixing it, isn't a straight forward process. The easiest way I found so far is using `grep` together with `jar tf` within a for-loop of a bash-shell. That obviously means that you need a Unix system or Cygwin:

```
for i in *.jar; do
    jar tf "$i" | grep ByteArrayOutputStream | grep -c commons > /dev/null && echo "$i"
done
```

Powershell might bring similar functionality, but I don't know Powershell.

This short script outputs all the jars, that contain a class of package *.commons.*.ByteArrayOutputStream. In my case, only commons-io-1.0.jar is outputted but you should see multiple filenames. Next step is to find out why these particular jars are in your classpath and decide on the next step like deleting one of the jars, etc.